# Elasticsearch Aggregation quite hard

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my first question on StackOverflow !!
I am quite stuck with Elasticsearch, so I was searching for help.

Here is my issue.
I have a list of people having WIN or LOST value for some events

input :

```
|name  | result | event|
------------------------
|Marc  | WIN    | game1|
|Marc  | WIN    | game2|
|Gabe  | WIN    | game1|
|James | WIN    | game1|
|James | LOST   | game2|
|John  | LOST   | game1|
|John  | LOST   | game2|
```

Let's say code above represent my datas.
What I want to obtain is 3 requests.

- 1 giving me players always winning (perfect winners)
- 1 giving me players always losing (perfect losers)
- 1 giving me players doing both (balanced)

First request returning Marc and Gabe, the two players that never lost :

```
{
  "name": "Marc"
},
{
  "name": "Gabe"
}
```

Second request returning James, because he lost a game and won an other :

```
{
  "name": "James"
}
```

Third request returning John that lost every games (guess he's bad) :

```
{
  "name": "John"
}
```

I've tried a few things, but I failed. Here are my tries :

I tried an aggregation on the Name, and I filtred (in the 'must' segment) on WIN or LOST results, but the players having WIN and LOST give me issues, because they appear in both winners and losers sets.

I wanted to do a join between players having WIN and players having LOST, to obtain a set of players having WIN and LOST, or exclude one set to another and obtain players having only WIN or only LOST, but it's a SQL way of thinking. It is not an Elasticsearch solution and the syntaxe does not allow to do this (Sadly I don't really manage to thing without sets of players)

An other solution is to create a single request displaying the player type (WINNER, LOSER, MID), then to apply a filter to take only the type wanted, but the sub aggregations gave me a hard time, and I totally failed in this path (if you have a solution, it would be great).

Lastly, a solution would be to display numbers of WIN and numbers of LOST for every player (and I did the request) but it is not exactly what I want because winners, losers and mid are melted.

```
GET /_search
{ 
    "size": 0, 
    "query": {
      "bool" : {
        "must": [],
        "filter": {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
                "lte": "30/08/2018",
                "gte": "27/06/2018",
                "format": "dd/MM/yyyy"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "my_buckets": {      
            "terms": {
                "field": "name.keyword",
                "size": 20
            },
            "aggs": {
                "GroupByType": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "result.keyword",
                        "size": 100
                    }
                }
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe a filter to take results having count of WIN > 0 and a count of LOST == 0 could do the job, but I didn't found the right syntaxe to do such thing.

So I'm running out of ideas, and I was hopping to find some help here.

Thanks in advance.
And don't hesitate to ask me more details if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: I doubt you ES will help you solve this specific problem. Even if it could solve this problem, then it will be at the cost of performance/resources. You should think of re-structuring your ES document in order to achieve this specific use-case.